# How to get a variable in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

**EDIT**
so i removed the first mention of encrypted, i get a new error. this time it generates a hash however the problem is with the function `dec()`

```js
node:internal/crypto/cipher:176
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Decipheriv.update (node:internal/crypto/cipher:176:11)
    at dec (C:\Coding\coding\JS\PasswordManager\index.js:31:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Coding\coding\JS\PasswordManager\index.js:37:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Also when i move the contents of `dec()` to `pass()` everything works fine. however, this wont really work for me.

I'm making a pasword manager for myself. As a coding challenge to get better and also for better security.

However, I'm trying to call the variable `encrypted`, which is defined in a function. However I get this error whenever I run my code.

```js
> node .
node:internal/crypto/cipher:176
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Cipheriv.update (node:internal/crypto/cipher:176:11)
    at pass (C:\Coding\coding\JS\PasswordManager\index.js:15:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Coding\coding\JS\PasswordManager\index.js:37:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

**CODE**

```js
function pass(length, username, service) {
    var length = length,
        charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.`~1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_=+{[}]|\;:'/?><",
        retVal = "",
        encrypted = cipher.update(compiled, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
    
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    var compiled = `${service}: ${username} | ${retVal}\n`

    var encrypted = cipher.update(compiled, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex'); // encrypted text
    
    console.log(encrypted);
    fs.appendFile('out.txt', encrypted+`\n`, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The login details were appended to file!');
      }) ;
    return encrypted;
    }
function dec() {
    var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8'); //deciphered text
    console.log(decrypted);
}
```

I have been trying to fix this for a while now, what do I do?

Comment: It's because you're trying to access compiled before it is initialized. Because of that, it's value is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `compiled` is being accessed before it is initialized.

```js
function pass(length, username, service) {
    var length = length,
        charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.`~1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_=+{[}]|\;:'/?><",
        retVal = "",
        encrypted = cipher.update(compiled, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex'); // Error here
    // Rest of code
}
```

In order to fix it, you need to initialize compiled before the call to `cipher.update()`.

And then, because you redeclare and initialize `encrypted` without using this value, you can remove the call completely:

```js
function pass(length, username, service){
    var length = length,
        charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.`~1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_=+{[}]|\;:'/?><",
        retVal = "";
    
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    var compiled = `${service}: ${username} | ${retVal}\n`

    var encrypted = cipher.update(compiled, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex'); // encrypted text
    
    console.log(encrypted);
    fs.appendFile('out.txt', encrypted+`\n`, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The login details were appended to file!');
      }) ;
    return encrypted;
}
```

Comment: The code has two calls the `cipher.update()`. They can probably just remove the first one.

Comment: The second one is after `compiled` is assigned.

Comment: not it. I moved it up there to try something out. it didnt work and forgot to change it back. still get an error,

Comment: If you remove the entire `encrypted` declaration and initialization, the code works fine.